# Using Common Layers access

Tags: javascript, java, json, openlayers-3

I am new to javascript. I am using alert option for displaying map layers. if alert option is true it has to display 4 layers. otherwise it has to display 2 layers.

Trying to write optimized code. 
Now I am displaying layers as `if(true){1,2,3,4} else{3,4}`. Trying to write optimized code`{3,4}` as common layers.

`if true{1,2, + common layers} else{display common layers}`. Somebody

suggest me code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this,

```
if(true){
  // Layer1, Layer2.
}
// Layer3,Layer4.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
switch(icheck){
case true :{1,2}; // no break statement used here

case false: {3,4};
             break;
default : //your Operation whatever you want to perform on this.
             break;
}
```

- If your case Statement is `true` then it will execute your `{1,2}` and from false case `{3,4}` because no break is used.
- If your case Statement is `false` then it will execute your `{3,4}` Only. After that it will break and go out of the switch.

I think this is a much better approach you should implement.

Thanks